# In unity what is C# jump script showing error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors

On unity using C# I made this jump script to control a player. When I run the code below I get the errors shown below

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float JumpForce;

    [SerializeField]
    bool isGrounded = false;

    Rigidbody2D RB;

    private void Awake()
    {
        RB = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            if(isGrounded == true)
            {
                RB.AddForce(Vector2.up*JumpForce);
                isGrounded = false;   
            }
        }
    }
    O refrences
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if(collision.gameObject.CompareTag("ground"))
        {
            if(isGrounded == false)
            {
                isGrounded = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason, I get no error inside of vs code but when I to the game it says what the picture below says. If you have an answer it would really help thanks.[image]

Comment: I can't explain Code not displaying the errors, but you are missing the `>` in `GetComponent<Rigidbody2D();`.

Comment: And the first two are no compiler errors but runtime warnings .. btw: there is absolutely no need/use try to hide the time stamp from us ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have configured everything correctly. An in-depth tutorial can be found here.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity

The warnings can happen when you change the name of a class or file and don't fix the script component on the scene game object. It can also give that warning if you change the code while in playmode.